# Variables from a list with further usage (Python)

Tags: python, variables

I have a list of strings like the following:

```
list = ['x','y','z']
```

For each of these, I need call a class within the Python file with these values as both the variable name and the object to be passed to the class, as follows:

```
x = Class('x')
y = Class('y')
z = Class('z')
```

This is all done within a class in a Python file and not at the command line. I have tried exec however I need to have access to these variables later and I don't know what the scope of exec is. Furthermore, exec is pretty nasty from what I have heard.

I would really appreciate some help with this. I have tried looking on Stack Overflow for answers but a lot of the solutions didn't make sense to me.

Thanks!

Comment: `d = {s: Class(s) for s in l}`. don't name your list `list` (it shadows the `list` name) and don't name your class `Class` as it's too generic. and the first part is a dictionary comprehension if you want to read more on it.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that produces a dictionary d which has {'x': 'Class(x)', 'y': 'Class(y)', 'z': 'Class(z)'} and, if so, how do I then instantiate x to be Class(x)? And apologies, 'list' and 'Class' were just example names.

Comment: cool, no prob. and yes, it produces a dictionary. you almost never want to do what you are trying, it indicates something else is wrong with the code. however, if you really want to do it, you can do `locals().update(d)`

Comment: but think about it, how are you going to create the variables programmatically but then access them statically in your code? and why?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['x','y','z']
for k in lst:
    exec(k + " = Class('" + k + "')")
```